# relational algebra expression and the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

> Use the following query to compute a new table.
>
> ```
> section_and_time =
>     π course_id, sec_id, semester, year, day, start_hr, start_min, end_hr, end_min
>         (section ⨝ time_slot)
> ```
>
> Using only section_and_time, write a relational algebra expression that returns a relation of overlapping courses of the form
>
> ```
> (course_id_1, sec_id_1, semester_1, year_1, course_id_2, sec_id_2, semester_2, year_2)
> ```
>
> Your table cannot contain duplicates. For example, a result containing
>
> ```
> (BIO-101,  1, fall, 2022, MATH-101, 2, fall, 2022)
> (MATH-101, 2, fall, 2022, BIO-101,  1, fall, 2022)
> ```
>
> is incorrect.

I've tried the following SQL query:

```
SELECT S1.course_id, S1.sec_id, S1.semester, S1.year, S2.course_id, S2.sec_id, S2.semester, S2.year
FROM section_and_time S1, section_and_time S2
WHERE (S1.course_id != S2.course_id)
AND NOT (S1.end_hr < S2.start_hr AND S1.end_min < S2.start_min)
```

But the joining of two section_and_time tables causes the joining to occur with every column. How can I do it so that 1 course_id will join with every course_id in the table?

Comment: A correct test for overlap is `greatest(S1.start_hr*60+S1.start_min,S2.start_hr*60+S2.start_min) < least(S1.end_hr*60+S1.end_min,S2.end_hr*60+S2.end_min)`

Comment: Please pick 1 language. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Please read the editor help re block formats for code & for quotes & for nesting them. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do.

Comment: This is an SQL duplicate. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se].